# Add translation only for a particular content type

Tags: views, nodes, i18n-l10n

I don't have much experience in Drupal and I am trying to create multilingual content for a particular content type. I want to switch the language inside the content instead of changing the whole site language. I have used the i18n module to do this but the whole site gets changing. For example I am using right to left languages like Arabic, Farsi etc. I am using views to list the items for this content type.

Answer (score 1):

It's by design...

Drupal Content translation using modules like i18n and locale works for complete site... For example if you are using Arabic language and if you add a arabic translation for a particular node, if you are viewing arabic version of node complete site changes from right to left..

As a work around..If you just want to add translations i would suggest use modules like [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [node clone](https://drupal.org/project/node_clone) to connect english version with other versions and use select box to choose language.. You need to add links to redirect user to other versions based on above reference logic.. Keep in mind by implementing above you will loose Drupal powerful Multilingual feature..

Comment: Thanks Anil. I am planning to keep the direction from left to right for all the languages so it won't break the site layout.